# How to allow a "return outside of function" syntax when running npm test?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Basically I have a simple if statement in a file responsible for setting up some async queue behavior.

```
//queue.js file
if (!myEnv) {
  console.log('queue env is not set');
  return;
}
```

It's an old legacy NodeJs 12.18.x application and I want to allow the return statement to be valid syntax when I run `npm test`.  Right now the test env spits out `Syntax Error...return' outside of function'`

Is there an easy workaround for this? The app is being sunsetted, so it doesn't make sense to turn this into a ton of work, just do the simplest solution and get out. If it helps there's an `.eslintrc.js` file and a `.prettierrc.js` file in the top level directory. Not sure if those files are impacting this error as it seems like from google it's a NodeJS error.

Comment: it spits out the correct conclusion: `return` outside of a function does nothing, and never has. The easiest workaround is to wrap your entire code as an immediately invoked anonymous function: `(function() { ...all your original code... })();` so that at least now `return` will exit the wrapping function.

Comment: `Throw new Error('queue env is not set')` instead of `return`.